# Using desktop as file explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Is there a way to use your desktop like file explorer?

Example:

1. open a folder on desktop
2. desktop refreshes
3. on the desktop are now the contents of the opened folder

My goal is to be able to navigate through folders this way

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In Windows 10 (not 11) you can make toolbar for your Desktop and then folders should flyout when you go to the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a program I use called [Fences](https://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) from [Stardock](https://www.stardock.com/).  The Folder Portals feature sounds very similar to what you want.  You can download a free trial and test it out.

Personally, I really like this program.  I have been using it for years and can recommend it.